# GraphViz and LaTeX; gives blank PDF

Tags: pdftex, diagrams, miktex, shell-escape, dot2texi

I've tried 4 different `.sty` files (most of which didn't work, some of which gave me errors on rendered page).

Now trying with the [dot2texi](https://dot2tex.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tipsandtricks.html#the-dot2texi-latex-package) package, which is giving me a blank PDF.

I have tried running `initexmf --edit-config-file=pdftex.ini` then adding: `EnableWrite18=t` to opened file, and I've tried adding `-shell-escape` to the run command:

[image: TeXWorks config]

Yet nothing has worked. **How can I write and successfully compile inline GraphViz diagrams in LaTeX?**

Comment: I noticed in your screenshot that you are using MiKTeX. AFAIK TeX engines provided by MiKTeX don't have the `--shell-escape` flag, but a similar flag named `--enable-write18` (or something along these lines). Could you try replacing the flag and tell us if it works? `:)`

Comment: Just tried that, unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: `--shell-escape` works fine with miktex. But the package needs external tools (according the documentation dot2tex and Graphviz). Are you sure that they are installed, that they work and are on your path?

Comment: @Ulrike: I thought `--shell-escape` was an invalid flag with MiKTeX, but it's been a while since I migrated from it to TeX Live. Is `--enable-write18` still valid?

Comment: @Paulo: Both will work.  There are "official" (documentated) switches and quite a lot of (undocumented) TeXLive-aliases - most of the switches that work with TeXLive works with miktex too.

Comment: @Ulrike: Thank you very much! I was unaware of the TeX Live aliases. I'm writing a manual about a TeX automation tool and there was a subsection where I mentioned about MiKTeX flags - I'll update it accordingly. `:)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

IMHO the problem does not rely on MiKTeX, but in the required programs that `dot2texi` relies on. The package has the following dependencies:

- [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org) - A graph visualization software.
- [`dot2tex`](https://dot2tex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) - A tool for converting graphs generated by GraphViz to formats suitable for use with LaTeX.

The first one is an easy-to-deploy `.msi` file - just double-click and install it in Windows. If I'm not mistaken, GraphViz even adds itself to the system path. You can check if the GraphViz tools are available by running `dot --help` in the command prompt:

[image: dot]

If you get a similar output, GraphViz is added to the system path.

Now, the second tool - `dot2tex` - is quite tricky for the average Windows user. This tool is actually a Python script and, well, relies on Python to run. Note that the script runs only in the `2.x` series (I have Python `3.x` in my development Windows machine and had to downgrade it in order to test the script). If you have Python `2.x` installed, I recommend you to use `easy_install` or `pip` to install `dot2tex`. Besides of installing it, make sure to include the `PYTHON_INSTALL/Scripts` directory to your system path in order to make the script available.

I have another option, in case you are not familiar with Python. I built an wrapper from the `dot2tex` sources and generated a standalone batteries-included `dot2tex.exe` file, [available here](https://github.com/cereda/codebucket/tree/master/windows). Unzip it and put `dot2tex.exe` somewhere in your computer. Make sure that the directory where `dot2tex.exe` rests is also in the system path. Testing `dot2tex --help` in the command prompt:

[image: Dot2Tex]

With GraphViz and `dot2tex` available in the system path, let's see this example from the package documentation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dot2texi}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{dot2tex}[neato,mathmode]
digraph G {
node [shape="circle"];
a_1 -> a_2 -> a_3 -> a_4 -> a_1;
}
\end{dot2tex}
\end{document}
```

By running `pdflatex --shell-escape myfile.tex`, we have the correct output:

[image]

The important parts from the `.log` file:

```
...
Package dot2texi Info: Automatically converting dot/neato files on input line 1
48.
...
\openout3 = `teste148-dot2tex-fig1.dot'.

 Opening dot2tex stream teste148-dot2tex-fig1.dot
runsystem(dot2tex --figonly -ftikz      --prog=neato -tmath  -o teste148-dot2te
x-fig1.tex  teste148-dot2tex-fig1.dot)...executed.

Package dot2texo Info: teste148-dot2tex-fig1.dot converted on input line 11.
...
```

Hope it helps. `:)`

Comment: Thanks, once again it didn't work, but trying it in a different folder with your test-case—then your test-case embedded into my full-text—amounted in a working, compiled PDF with embedded GraphViz. I have no idea what's going on with my computer, and why I need to move folders everytime I require a new sty. :\

Comment: @AT: I have no idea why the folder influenced the output. Maybe it was some sort of name clash. I used the `dot2texi` package that is shipped with TeX Live (I checked that MiKTeX also comes with it), what if you use that version instead of a local `.sty` in your folder? Thanks for accepting my humble answer. `:)`

Comment: Nahh, it wasn't a name-clash, nor was it anything distro specific (I installed TeX Live to confirm). Even now I can't figure it out properly, e.g.: I take my two .tex files and copy them into a new directory; the outputted PDF doesn't include the graphviz diagrams >.<

Comment: I did end up finding the issue BTW, had a space in my filename >.<

Comment: @AT: Ah cool! I forgot about checking the filename. `:)`

Comment: Amazing! I never knew about the dot2texi package. Is it possible to make the generate graph appear smaller?

Comment: The `dot2tex` link is dead.